# std::multiset::iterator = NULL no longer valid?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some code that I'm updating to C++11 using gcc 4.7 (from 3.1)

I have a multiset defined as a private member of a class:

```
multiset <Object*, objectcomp> objects_;
```

In the code is a segment that looks like this (p_q is a pair of multiset iterators, sorry about that nasty line, can't wait to replace that with auto, haha):

```
void Terrain::removeObject(Object* obj){
    pair<multiset<Object*, objectcomp>::iterator, multiset<Object*, objectcomp>::iterator> p_q;
    multiset<Object*, objectcomp>::iterator p,q;
    q = NULL;
    p_q = objects_.equal_range(obj);
    for(p = p_q.first; p != p_q.second; p++){
        if(*p == obj) {q=p; break;}
    }
    if(q!=NULL){
        ... do stuff based on q no longer being null
    }
}
```

This won't compile anymore. Can you not set iterators to null anymore? What is the alternative? (nullptr doesn't work either)

Comment: This was **never** valid.

Comment: oh, well that's embarassing, haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was never legal to set iterators to NULL. You may have gotten lucky because your particular implementation happened to use pointers as iterators for that type, but it was still illegal.

The right answer is:

```
q = objects_.end();
```

Or, in some cases:

```
q = multiset<Object*, objectcomp>::iterator();
```

Comment: Anyone know why my first code block is not showing up as code?

Comment: Copying and pasting didn't work… but removing the `_`, then cutting, then pasting, did… Weird…

Comment: Originally you had non-breaking spaces instead of proper spaces; apparently SO doesn't count non-breaking spaces as indenting whitespace.

Comment: Implementing a compliant `std::multiset::iterator` as a raw pointer is probably impossible. I'd guess it might have worked because the corresponding class was implicitly convertible from `NULL`.

Comment: @AndreyT: It couldn't be a pointer to a collection of node pointers? I'm not sure why you'd do that, but I can't see why it would be impossible… But you're right, it probably was an unwanted implicit conversion (which probably became explicit in C++11 and/or the new g++/libstdc++, hence his error).

Comment: @abarnert: The problem is that `it++` must point to the next value, as defined by the predicate of `multiset`. If `it` is a raw pointer, `it++` points to the next location in memory.

Comment: @abarnert: In order to iterate over a data structure different from a continuous array, one would need overloaded `++` operator. C++ does not allow overloading for pointer types, which basically eliminates the possibility of it being a raw pointer.

Comment: @AndreyT: Let's say I had the `multiset` handle iteration by building an array of `struct`s full of node pointers as you try to iterate it. Then `operator++` obviously works. It's possible that one of the documented performance guarantees makes it illegal to do that, but otherwise, it seems like a stupid but legal implementation.

Comment: @abarnert: In such implementation the unary `*` will not do what it is supposed to do. It will give a node pointer instead of the node itself. And you cannot overload `*` either.

Comment: @AndreyT: Well, it'll give a struct of node pointers… but you're right, that's not the actual node.

Answer (score 2):

You never could set an iterator to NULL. If the above code ever worked, it was by sheer accident. Given any reasonable implementation of multiset, it's hard to see how it could ever have compiled, let alone run.

The best way to get a "nowhere" iterator is to use the end of the container. Replace `q = NULL` with `q = objects_.end()`.

Also, never put raw pointers in a container; it's an open invitation to memory leaks. You almost certainly want either `multiset<Object,comp>` or `multiset<shared_ptr<Object>,comp>`.

Comment: I've never even heard of shared_ptr I guess I'll look that up. Thanks for the **pointers**.

Comment: +1 for the point about not using raw pointers in a container. @EricB: Also take a look at [boost::ptr_container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html), which lets the container own the pointed-to objects. If the objects don't need to stay alive after they've left the container (or only need to stay alive until the end of the current scope if they've left the container), it may be much simpler (and more efficient) than a container of shared pointers.